# How can the default/inbuilt namespace be accessed in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The library i'm working with is written in JS. I'm trying to write the .d.ts to something better than the autogenerated types. The library implements its own variant of standard data types (for synchronization purposes).

For example, they implemented their own Map. Internally, they also use the standard es6 map. Unfortunately, i can't access it, because they already named something Map.

```
    export class Map {

    }

    export const test: global.Map<string, string>();
    // I want this to be the es6 Map.
```

Comment: I suppose you can just pick an alias when importing their `Map`?

Comment: `import { Map as TheirLibraryMap } from 'their-library';`

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai I'm writing the .d.ts file, is there a way to alias it in that stage?

Comment: @blackening That will be `export { Map as TheirMap };`

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai thanks, i did the opposite, declaring TheirMap and `export { TheirMap as Map }`.